# apt-get behaves differently when using loop structure

Tags: bash, apt-get

I have a bash script which installs a set of packages from a file but it fails to find the packages.  When executing the same commands from the bash terminal, there is no problem.

sources.list:

```
apt-transport-https
curl
```

BROKEN:

```
apt-get update
dl_flag=--download-only
pkglist=source.list
while read pkg; do
    apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades "$dl_flag" "$pkg"
done <"$pkglist"
```

apt-get claims it can't find anything:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package curl
```

When doing the same commands from a terminal, everything is just fine...

```
# apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades --download-only curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal libcurl3-gnutls libffi6 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhogweed4 libhx509-5-heimdal libidn11
  libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libnettle6 libp11-kit0
  libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-6
  libwind0-heimdal openssl
Suggested packages:
  gnutls-bin krb5-doc krb5-user libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-sql libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
  | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates curl krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal libcurl3-gnutls libffi6 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhogweed4 libhx509-5-heimdal libidn11
  libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libnettle6 libp11-kit0
  libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-6
  libwind0-heimdal openssl
0 upgraded, 34 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 5324 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I can't think of anything that would cause the loop to behave differently.

Comment: How exactly are you running the script?

Comment: Have you made sure that `source.list` doesn't contain carriage returns?

Answer (score 0):

Source.list contained carriage returns which were passed to the loop steps that broke the script.

I also found a note that the sources file should end in a line-feed to ensure proper parsing by the read function.